# Permission denied trying to append to a file in a mounted directory

Tags: linux, unix, file-permissions

I am having trouble understanding why I am unable to append to a file in python3 (3.2.3). I create these files in a shared folder but I am unable to append to them. There are no issues with files in my home folder. The shared folder permissions are:

```
drwxrwxrwx  2 nobody   share       65536 2017-01-01 22:16 Pictures
```

I am in the 'share' group which has all the permissions:

```
groups alex
share www-data
```

I can create the file:

```
>>> testFile=open ('VID_2.mp4', 'wb')
>>> testFile.close()
```

But I cannot append to it:

```
>>> testFile=open ('VID_2.mp4', 'ab')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'VID_2.mp4'
```

I checked the file permissions and, from my understanding, I should be able to append to that file:

```
ls -l
-rw-rw-rw- 1 alex share 0 2017-01-01 22:40 VID_2.mp4
```

So I am baffled as to why the permission to append is denied, and what permission would be required to allow the append.

UPDATE:
It seems the issue is not with the python script since I get the same permission error if I use `echo`:

```
touch myfile.txt
echo 1 > myfile.txt
echo 2 >> myfile.txt
-bash: myfile.txt Permission denied
ls -l myfile.txt
-rw-rw-rw- 1 alex share 2 2017-01-03 09:44 myfile.txt
```

UPDATE 2:

These folders are under a regular mount (/DataVolume):

```
/dev/sda4 on /DataVolume type ext4 (rw,noatime,nodiratime)
/DataVolume/cache on /CacheVolume type none (rw,bind)
/DataVolume/shares on /shares type none (rw,bind)
/DataVolume/shares on /nfs type none (rw,bind)

cat /proc/mounts
/dev/sda4 /DataVolume ext4 rw,noatime,nodiratime,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/sda4 /CacheVolume ext4 rw,noatime,nodiratime,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/sda4 /shares ext4 rw,noatime,nodiratime,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/sda4 /nfs ext4 rw,noatime,nodiratime,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0
```

I can append to files in `/DataVolume/home/alex` but not to files under `/DataVolume/shares`:

```
ls -l /DataVolume/
drwxrwxr-x  4 root root      65536 2013-11-14 21:15 home
drwxrwxr-x  7 root share     65536 2017-01-04 10:16 shares
ls -l /DataVolume/home/
drwxr-xr-x 7 alex   share 65536 2017-01-01 22:24 alex
ls -l /DataVolume/home/alex
-rw-rw-rw- 1 alex share     4 2017-01-04 10:20 test.txt
ls -l /DataVolume/shares/
drwxrwxrw-  2 alex   share 65536 2017-01-04 10:23 test
```

EDIT: I no longer have the device in question, so I won't be able to verify any of the suggestions anymore.

Comment: The write permissions allow to append to a file, so there is something wrong with your Python script (in the parts that are not shown in the question). Have you tried to test the permissions in pure shell? E.g. `cd Pictures; touch file; echo 1 > file`. By the way, it is not obvious from the script that you are opening the file in `Pictures` directory.

Comment: `echo 1 > file` works, but a subsequent `echo 1 >> file` does not (same permission error). I will update my answer.

Comment: Is your Pictures folder on a local file system or is it mounted from somewhere?  If there is a mount or bindfs on the particular directory, it can mess up "standard" unix permissions.

Comment: What happens if you cd /tmp and execute your shell test (touch, echo etc) there? Does it produce the same result, or does echo 2 >> myfile.txt now work?

Comment: testing on `/tmp` has no issues. The Pictures folder is a sub-subfolder of a regular ext4 mount. `/dev/sda4 on /DataVolume type ext4 (rw,noatime,nodiratime)`. One of the parents is also binded to other folders but I am not using those. I think there is something about this mount. I created a new folder under it (owned by me and I still cannot append)

Comment: Did you by any chance do a `mount -o bind,ro ...` to establish the bind mounts? If so, you've set your primary file system to read-only also, probably. That may be a somewhat surprising result with bind mounts, but it's how they work. You should have gotten some error messages or something, though, if you attempted that, and you would have had to use additional options to force it.

Comment: There is no ro bind. In addition, since I can create new files and write to them, the system is not read-only. It's only appending to files that is denied

Comment: Does the directory have a default ACL? You can check with `getfacl directoryname` . It'd show up as `default:something:or:other`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I no longer have the device in question. So I will not be able to verify any of this anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Check your `umask` settings, the file is not getting executable permissions after creation. `umask 002` should fix this.

-rw-rw-rw- 1 alex share 2 2017-01-03 09:44 myfile.txt

Comment: Executable permissions are not required to append/write to a file as far as I know. Also doesn't `umask 002` mean --wx-wx--x ?

Comment: @ Mahaalaxmi: OP shows perms are open for file created, so not umask. Also 'umask 002' as described would be -rw-rw-r--.
@ Alecz, no, unask 002 means -rw-rw-r--. umask is a /mask/, binary opposite of chmod. umask 002 masks off the 002 bit from the normal 666 perms, making it 664.
OP, is this MacOSX? Sounds like either weird mount flags (which usurp normal unix perms) or perhaps a non-unix file system is mounted (Windows?) where unix perms are emulated, and/or ACL permissions are in effect (see 'ls -la@', @ shows ACLs) Also check for sticky/setuid/gid bits on parent dirs.

Comment: @erco, the device was a Western Digital My Book Live which runs Debian on a PowerPC architecture. As you can see from my post, this was a regular mount of /dev/sda4 to /DataVolume as ext4.